# lodash not available through webpack configuration

Tags: webpack

My webpack.config.js is pasted below.  I am trying to have d3 and _ from lodash available as globals from in all modules.  D3 is working but lodash is not coming through:

```
"use strict";
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var bower_dir = path.join(__dirname, '/bower_components');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

var config = {
    addVendor: function(name, path){
        this.resolve.alias[name] = path;
        this.module.noParse.push(path);
    },
    entry: {
        app: ["./app/js/index.js"],
        vendors: ["d3", "_"]
    },
    output: {
        "path": process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? './dist' : './build',
        "filename": "bundle.js"
    },
    module: {
        noParse: [],
        loaders: [
      { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader?root=." },
      { test: /\.js?$/, exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/, loader: 'babel' },
      { test: /\.gif$/, loader: "url-loader?mimetype=image/png" },
      // { test: /bootstrap\/js\//, loader: 'imports?jQuery=jquery' },
      { test: /.(png|woff(2)?|eot|ttf|svg)(\?[a-z0-9=\.]+)?$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000' }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {},
    root: [path.join(__dirname, "app/css"), path.join(__dirname, "app/js")]
    },
    plugins: [
        // This plugin makes a module available as variable in every module
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            d3: "d3",
      "_": "_"
        }),
        // CommonsChunkPlugin will take the vendors chunk and create a commonly used js file
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin('vendors','vendors.js', Infinity),
    // https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-webpack-plugin
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: 'D3 and react',
      template: 'build/index.html'
    })
    ]

};

config.addVendor('d3', bower_dir + '/d3/d3.min.js');
config.addVendor('_', bower_dir + '/lodash/lodash.min.js');

module.exports = config;
```

Comment: @StefanYohansson I am

Comment: @dagda1 how did you resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

What if:

```
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        d3: "d3",
        "_": "lodash"
    })
```

and resolve alias:

```
alias: {
    lodash: <path to lodash>
}
```

Comment: When use a `ProvidePlugin` put inside object: `"_": "lodash", "window._": "lodash"`