# GroupBy in formarray validator - 'groupBy not a function' Error

Tags: forms, angular, typescript, group-by

I have created a dynamic form for my class

```
public export class ObjectConfig
{
fields: Field[];
}
public export class Field
{
name: string;
datatype: string;
}
```

For field array component I am using a custom validator as follows:

```
private customGroupValidation(formArray) {
        console.log('validation fired');
        let isError = false;
        var result = formArray.controls.groupBy( c => {
            console.log('group by value :' + c.value.name);
            return c.value.name;

        });
        for (let prop in result) {
            if (result[prop].length > 1) {

                isError = true;
                result[prop].forEach(function (item:FormControl) {
                    item.status = "INVALID";
                });
            } else {
                result[prop][0]._status = 'VALID';           
            }
        }
        if(isError){ return {'duplicate':'duplicate entries'}}
    }
```

I am using the example [here](https://eyalvardi.wordpress.com/2016/08/28/custom-group-validation-in-angular-2/)

I am getting the error "**formarray.controls.groupBy is not a function**"

Can anyone help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From example linK:

> Now let’s see the custom group validation method. **I used groupBy
>   method of lodash librar**y to detect if there are any groups of more
>   than one item, which means that we have duplicate names.

Do you use **lodash** in your project?

Comment: so you need to use it. Becuase groupBy feature is not present in angular, it comes from **lodash**

Comment: can you please direct me to a link.. m unable to configure lodash webpack plugin

Comment: lodash is a js library. Add a package via npm and configure just like any other js library in webpack. It's just a utility tools for javascript. I am no webpack guru, but I thinks it's somewhere here: https://webpack.github.io/docs/library-and-externals.html

Answer (score 1):

`groupBy` is not a function of `formarray.controls`. In your example link its using `lodash.js` which is providing `groupBy` function. Check plnkr for [custom group validation in angular 2](http://embed.plnkr.co/bOxBqf5iz3WjYZtce7Ky/)

Comment: its same link for your given example link and its working. http://embed.plnkr.co/bOxBqf5iz3WjYZtce7Ky/

Comment: check that plunker's `index.html` file in which author has added `lodash.js` and used `groupBy` function of it.

Comment: m using webpack, what changes do I need to make for it??

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34805938/lodash-not-available-through-webpack-configuration or https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash-webpack-plugin. may be it will help you